Redocly Response Description on Same Line
I get the following two displays. I prefer the response code and description on the same line. Sometimes it gets displayed on one line and other times, on two lines. The code is identical. What causes the difference?

But other times I get this:

  responses:
    '400':
      description: Bad request. The request was malformed or invalid.


This seems like a media query issue.  Are you viewing on the same size window?  When does it change?  Provide more details on the browser and any conditions of when and how you build Redoc and your operating system

Thanks! I researching a response, I noticed the double line was only in the preview mode. The rendered HTML version has the correct single line. I think that's good enough for me.
